# MSI "Registry on Target Machine" vs 2008 WPF

Tags: registry, windows-installer, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've developped a wpf application.
I created a setup project.
I tried to add in the setup the installation of a registry key it doesn't work.
I don't get because Im sure my key is right to right path, because I first tried to create it manually and I imported it in my setup, which worked fine.
Then I deleted it manually in my registry key for tests  but when I run my setup the registry key is not installed.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you installing the package on a x64 machine? If so, you might want to "Wow6432Node" registry hive, this is where registry entries created by x86 setup packages are being placed.